# How to replace values for similar group by mean?

Tags: r

I ha ve this data frame here

```
df = structure(list(D = c(-76, -74, -72, -70, -44, -42), A = c(83, 
83, 82, 82, 81, 81), B = c(-0.613, -0.4,-0.5, -0.68, -0.13, -0.26)), row.names = c(NA, 
 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to compute the mean of all values in B that have similar value in A.

for instance -0.613 and -0.4  as they correspond to the same values 83  etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(B ~ A, df, mean)
```

Or if we need a new column

```
df$Bmean <- with(df, ave(B, A))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   summarise(B = mean(B, na.rm = TRUE))
```

If we want to create a new column use `mutate`

```
df %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(Bmean = mean(B, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Bmean := mean(B, na.rm = TRUE), A]
```